# How to use strings stored in vectors in another function

Tags: r, string, for-loop, libraries

Hello i'm trying this for loop in which i enable multiple libraries in r.

```
lbs<-c("plyr","dplyr","magrittr","readr")

for (i in 1:length(lbs)) {

       library(lb[i])

      }
```

but i get this error

```
 Error in library(lb[i]) : 'package' must be of length 1
```

My questions covers two dillemas.

1. How do i use strings stored in vectors to use them in another function?
2. How do i tell rstudio to enable certain libraries by default every time in open r.

Answer (score 2):

In short:

1. The `library()` function is weird. Try `library(lb[i],character.only = TRUE)`. There is an example illustrating this at the very bottom of `?library`, for what it's worth.
2. Read `?Startup`, in particular about using `.Rprofile` files.

Comment: will     "character.only = TRUE" work for other functions as well?

Comment: @DennisAguilar No. There are different approaches to providing alternatives to nonstandard evaluation across base R and various packages. There are some common patterns, but library() is sort of an outlier in how it handles it.